# Выбор адреса с выпадающего списка

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap, select, список

Как реализовать выпадающий список с названиями Компаний, чтобы при выборе одного из них под списком появлялся адрес выбранной компании. Проект делаю на Wordpress Bootstrap 3[image: пример]

Comment: Покажите html-разметку или дайте ссылку на сайт. К WP вопрос отношения не имеет, это jQuery.

Comment: Нету еще сайта, есть макет, я его прикрепил. Нужен просто толчок или пример как это реализовать. Поделитесь, если есть мысли.

Comment: На select вешаете `.on('change', ...`, в обработчике выводите адрес выбранной компании, взятый из select. У вас же в select есть все адреса компаний?

Comment: Можете написать как таким способом реализовать то что мне нужно. Например есть select - 1,2,3, при выборе 1 под ним появляется текст "один", при выборе 2 меняется на "два" и т д

Comment: Вы приведите select в виде html-кода прямо в вопросе. Тогда мы уйдем от непонимания. Вопросы без кода здесь совсем не приветствуются.

Comment: <select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

Comment: У вас в select нет текста "один", "два" - где код его возьмет?

Comment: Ну так в этом и вопрос)) Как сделать чтобы при выборе <option>1</option> появлялся текст, допустим <p>один<p>

Comment: Где это текст существует, если не в select? Код его выдумать должен? Попытайтесь сконцентрироваться и всё-таки поставить вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было ответить.

Comment: Вопрос мой выше в тексте вопроса, откуда мне знать, куда что писать, поэтому и спрашиваю, знал бы, не спрашивал бы

Comment: Вот как есть табы (вкладки), при выборе одной открывается одна информация, при выборе второй - другая. Так же нужно, только вместо табов выпадающий список.

Comment: Тут дело в том что нужен вывод информации, которой в селекте нету. Может как то через display:none и display: block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос

```js
$(document).ready(function(){});
function load_sklad(el){ $('#sklad_info').html($('#preload div[sklad="'+$(el).val()+'"]').html()); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preload" style="display:none"> <div sklad="1">один</div><div sklad="2">два</div><div sklad="3">три</div> </div> <select onchange="load_sklad(this)"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option </select> <div id="sklad_info">один</div>
```